# Building project when changing the JRE, on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have a project that compiles and runs well with `JRE6`, but when I changed to `JRE7` I found many compilation problems.

I have re-changed the `JRE` on run configuration to `JRE6` but the problem persists.

Here is an example:

```
public static class SaveInDBAction extends AbstractAction {
    public SaveInDBAction() {
    }
//staff
}
```

That class is defined on a file named `EditorActions.java` and the error was:

```
Illegal modifier of the class SaveInDBAction...
```

I tried to rebuild and even recopied the project to a new one but in vain, is there any suggestions?

Comment: Did you remove the JRE6 library from the build path and put in the JRE7. Also did you go to the "Java Compiler" tab in your project properties and change the compliance level to 1.7? If you didnt do either 1 of those it could cause errors to show up.

Comment: ot working, how can i get the old configuration of JRE6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video that will help you to do what you want:
http://www.javavids.com/video/how-to-change-jre--jdk-in-eclipse-project.html

The site states:

> Right click your project and choose properties. Select Java Build Path
>   -> Libraries, select JRE System Library, click Edit and choose whichever JRE or JDK you like.

Hope that solved it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i tried that, i don't know really where is the problem, I even uninstalled JRE7 and reconfigured my project but the errors remain

Comment: hmm.. that is as far as my knowledge goes on this topic :)